# Parsing text in feature class attachments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, search, attachments, elasticsearch, parse

Is there any way to parse text in feature class attachments using ArcGIS Desktop?

I have a feature class with ~60,000 features, all of which have an associated .pdf file.  I would like to query the text in these reports spatially.

I guess I could output the text in the .pdf's to a db, but ideally the search would just parse the .pdf files.

Comment: Output text from individual PDF and save in attachment?

Comment: sure, but then how do you search/parse an attached file to a feature class?

Comment: Extract to same file, search, mark feature if found, go to next feature. I use similar technique to resamle 1000s of attached photos.

Comment: Thanks for the process @FelixIP, could you go into a little more detail with that?  I'm not GIS expert, I've just learned what I needed for geology/mineral exploration, so a simplified version would be really appreciated.